# How do I get all attributes of a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to inspect what are the default arguments that matplotlib uses when we do a plot. For example, what's the size used for the axis, or title, or labels?

I created a minimal plot making

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
t = plt.gca().plot([1, 2])
```

And then trying some built in functions to get the arguments used, such as

```
dir(t)
t.__dir__()
```

But that didn't help me much

To be clear, I don't want to know exactly the size of text used; A google search would probably tell me that. I'm looking for a way so that I can find any defaults used by just inspecting an object

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this. [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) has what I was looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).